# Safari redirecting to http instead of https

Tags: macos, safari, http

When using Safari 14.0.3 on Mojave, if I paste https://gramhum.com in the address bar, I am redirected to greatfon.com, but the "https://" part disappears and the query is sent unencrypted via port 80. It is blocked by the firewall, so it fails.

I have to manually retype the URL to make it work. Same thing happens if I click the link inside an HTML file.

The option "Show full website address" is enabled, and if I replace https://gramhum.com with https://greatfon.com, it works.

I have no problem with Firefox and Chrome (these browsers redirect properly to http**s**://greatfon.com).

Comment: Is there not a padlock icon before the URL? Do you have a Proxy?

Comment: What version of Safari? Safari 14.0.3 tells me that anywebsite.com's certificate expired Monday, 24 August 2020 at 09:59:59 Australian Eastern Standard Time

Comment: I think the web address in the post is a 'fake' address, like `somebody@gmail.com` or 'yoyodyne.com`.

Comment: @IconDaemon I did wonder if that were the case. Then I would like some real examples.

Comment: @Gilby I corrected my post. The issue affects a domain in particular. It has a secure certificate by Cloudflare.

Comment: For me Safari 14.0.3 on macOS 11.2.3 both `https://gramhum.com` and `http://gramhum.com` redirect to `https://greatfon.com` which I gather is what you expect.

Comment: Yes that's the expected behavior. I run safari 14.0.3 on Mojave. Port 80, trustd and  Apple network 17.0.0.0/16 are blocked.

Comment: And if you remove your blocks?

Comment: It didn't work. edit: I meant 17.0.0.0/8 Actually I am redirected but to the http version instead of https. Did you try pasting https://gramhum.com in the address bar?

Comment: Yes, I pasted `https://gramhum.com` in the address bar.  also did it by typing it in.  always redirects to the https. (I guessed you meant 17.0.0.0/8)

Comment: Okay then thanks. I modified all the links so I don't need a solution anymore but I still wish I knew why it doesn't work with Safari.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you may be seeing a feature that was a bit controversial when Apple introduced it, namely, *not showing the full website address.*

If you go to `Safari > Preferences > Advanced` and check "Show full website address." and then once you are on "https://anywebsite.com" just click once in the address field. That should show everything *including* the http/https string.

Does that solve your issue? If not please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/419029/edit) your question and add some more details so we can assist.

Comment: "Show full website address" is enabled.